# Using rails has_scope gem to scope the last x number of items in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, has-scope

I'm using the has_scope gem.

I want to scope the last x number of items in an array of Articles in my database

something like this:

```
scope :last_few_items, -> num { Article.last(num) }
```

so in my querystring I could say www.bla.com?last_few_items=2
to return the last 2 items of an array

but all the examples I see for has_scope use this syntax:

```
scope :scope_name, -> vartopass { where(attribute_val: vartopass)}
```

wher 'attribute_val' are all attributes from my database... so I'm not really sure how to get what I want... aside from making a new route and a new controller that defines @articles = Article.last(2)  or something like that

Answer (score 0):

This is extracted from your question:

> wher 'attribute_val' are all attributes from my database... so I'm not really sure how to get what I want... aside from making a new route and a new controller that defines **@articles = Article.last(2) or something like that**

Did you tried it? This is actually the right way to do it, Rails natively implement `last(n)`

Comment: yep.  That works... I was just wondering if there was a way to filter it in the querystring, without having to make a new route for some strange list.

Comment: Well, you need to get the data (i.e. how many records) from somewhere right? if you are doing a get request it is necessary in your query-string. Or you perhaps implement a complex thing with your javascript updating a cookie on your client side so you keep your url clean. But some people (rare, but still) are disabling cookies